# add 15 days to a date with different formating

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to create a calculated column that adds 15 days to the EndDate field and then output it with a `YYYY/MM/DD` format, but I am not getting the desired results. Here is what my column looks like:

```
=(YEAR(EndDate)&"/"&MONTH(EndDate)&"/"&DAY(EndDate+15))
```

what is possible wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint stores dates as integer count starting at 1/1/1900

So

```
=EndDate + 15
```

gets you 15 days from your EndDate

To format Dates different you can use the `TEXT()`  function

```
=TEXT( EndDate+15 , "YYYY/MM/DD"  )
```

Function documentation: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List